# Form with FormFunction problem

Tags: interface

I've this form:

```
f[a_, b_] := a + b;
form = FormFunction[FormObject[<|"a" -> "Number", "b" -> "Number"|>], f[#a, #b] &];
form[]
```

How I can automatically bring up the form after the output display? (If I insert 3 and 2 and I click submit, it return 5. After 5, I'd like to see the form again.)
And can I remove "Cancel" or assign it an action like "Submit" button?
Thanks

Comment: Broadly, what are you trying to accomplish?  Is it necessary that `FormFunction` be used?

Answer (score 1):

The `form[]` can be returned as the output.

```
f[a_, b_] := a + b;

form = FormFunction[
   FormObject[<|"a" -> "Number", "b" -> "Number"|>], (Print@f[#a, #b]; form[]) &];

form[]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved with

```
f[a_, b_] := a + b;
FormPage[{"a" -> "Number", "b" -> "Number"}, f[#a, #b] &]
```

The result is show below the form.

Comment: I've an other problem with this type of form but with an other example. I've a function f with different Print. The output is show below the form but Print's output are shown in an other window (a notebook called "Message"). How can I disable this notebook to show its contents directly below the result of the function?